# Issue in Fetching the Data from Apache Ignite using Node Express

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, ignite

I am new to Apache Ignite.Can someone help me on how to fetch and load the data from ignite cache 
using node js without using sql field queries option. Cache is loaded using CacheJDBCPOJO Store and the Key and Value types are custom types defined using JAVA.As these classes are defined in Java not sure on how to fetch the data using node.

Hope the following example , explains the issue better.

We have ignite cache of custom key Type i.e Person Key with attributes Person First Name and person Last Name and custom value type  i.e Person Info with attributes Person Address and Person Age etc.
 These classes are defined in Java and the caches are configured in Bean File and loaded using CacheJDBCPOJO Store.

As these classes will not be available in node js, how can we load /fetch the data from node js using cahe.put /cache.get.Tried creating similar classes in node and pass the object of these classes to 
cahe.put /cache.get but it is in't working.

Comment: "but it is in't working" - what's the error?

Comment: Hi 

Pasted below  error i got.Actually i am trying query an existing cache using node js which is loaded via Cache JDBC Pojo Store in Java.It would be really helpful  if you share me any sample code.


ERROR: Binary type has different field types [typeName=OrderId, fieldName=OrderID, fieldTypeName1=long, fieldTypeName2=double]
(node:13596) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: igniteClient is not defined
    at start (C:\Users\ngovind\NodeApp\NodeIgnite.js:44:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

Comment: Also We are trying to build an Rest API on top of ignite cache using node express.

Can you please let me know whether there is a way to directly convert the sql 
fields query output to JSON using node express.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.It is really Helpful.Can't we convert an SQL Fields Query Output to JSON using node js.?

Comment: Are we talking about REST or node.js? Both have SQL support.

Comment: We are building Rest API by fetching data from Ignite Cache using SQL Fields Query API provided by ignite but these is returning a cursor which consists the rows of the Cache.To convert this to JSON i need field names.

Comment: Have you tried `cursor.getFieldNames()` as per [example](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/nodejs/examples/SqlExample.js)?

Comment: Yeah it is not returning any data.Even i executed the same code given in example.

Comment: Current i am using the following code to convert to json .
This is taking time as we to loop through each row in the cursor

var dataProductDetails=cursor._values ;

var res_data_prddetails=[];

var fields=[field1,field2]
    
        await dataProductDetails.map(function(arr){
                                 var prdobj={};
                                 fields.forEach((k,v)=> prdobj[k]=arr[v]);
                                 res_data_prddetails.push(prdobj);
                               }
                                    
                               
          );

Comment: Is there a direct function in js to map fields to array of values.
    Tried using _.object but it is working only if the values array has 
    one row.

Comment: I have updated answer regarding getFieldNames()

Answer (score 0):

I can see the following error:

```
ERROR: Binary type has different field types [typeName=OrderId, fieldName=OrderID, fieldTypeName1=long, fieldTypeName2=double] (node:13596)
```

Which will probably be fixed by removing ignite work dir (/tmp/ignite/work or ./ignite/work by default) and restarting all your nodes, and as such, not related directly to node.js

As for examples, have you tried the following:
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/nodejs-thin-client-binary-types

As for REST API, it should convert BinaryObject's to JSON by default, this should include all SQL columns' values.

*Update*: Turns out you have to do `query.setIncludeFieldNames(true)` to make `getFieldNames()` return field names.

Comment: Thank You so much. Now i am able to get the field names after setting this property.